# All Calendar events "changed" after WP8 to WP10 update

Tags: calendars, google

Our corporate calendar is in Google Apps for Business, which I was connecting to via my WP8 phone.  When I updated to WP10 this morning, when the new calendar app sync'ed it pinged every event in every calendar I have access to, triggering many thousands of "Event Changed" emails across the organization.

It's embarrassing, but not really catastrophic.  What I really need to know is if the calendar app actually changed these events, or if they just got pinged.

Does anybody know?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been a while and nobody seems to have the same issue. But since this question keeps getting votes, I'll just note that the events were not actually changed.  They just got pinged.